# TextChanged doesn't fire when removing text

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, textchanged

I have built an editing page.  There is a comments section and the possibility exists that the comments may need to be removed.

I have committed to using `TextChanged` as the users were worried about clicking buttons (rolls eyes).  I'm creating the event dynamically like this:

```
txtComments.TextChanged += UpdateComments;
```

The event works fine if there is anything in the textbox but if all text is removed then the event doesn't fire.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Ajax?

Comment: Do you have any validation that could cause it to not post back if the field is empty?

Comment: Are you clearing the text programatically?

Comment: I am not using Ajax nor am I validating for an empty field.  The text update is an action taken by the end user.  Thanks!

Comment: Additionaly, if I enter a space the event fires. It only fails when I remove all text.

Comment: Have you set AutoPostBack to 'true'?

Comment: yes.  it works fine if I change text.  It fails only when there is no text left.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN of the [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control:

> The TextChanged event is raised when the content of the text box changes between posts to the server. The event is only raised if the text is changed by the user; the event is not raised if the text is changed programmatically.

Clearing the `TextBox` between posts with code will cause the behavior you are describing (no event firing).

Comment: I read that before posting.  I am not changing the text programatically. I would think that no text vs any text would still be considered a change in text

Answer (score 0):

The method will always run if the value of the textbox has changed since the last post to the server. It will compare the value currently to the one that was last sent to the server and decide if the method should be invoked.

Comment: I agree with your comment but that is not what's happening.  I can delete the entire sentance and nothing happens but if I delete it all but add a space the event fires.

Comment: Any chance you can post some of your code? I'll check it out and see if I notice anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Since your element is being created dynamically, then make sure that you set event handler on each post back. I believe you must set it on Pre_Init vs Page_Load but I have not dealt with the ASP.NET page life cycle in a while. Here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm clearly not doing a good job of clarifying.  txtComments is being dynamically created.  It is updated using the current comments from a db.  The User can then Modify the comments, and upon textbox exit UpdateComments() event is called.  I appreciate the help on this!

Comment: Edited the response now that it is clear that the textbox is being dynamically created.

Comment: I have read through that document.  It is useful information but the event is fired in any instance of change *except* if the comment is completely removed.  If I insert enter only a space the event fires and the update occurs.  If I modify the string in any way and there are multiple characters, the event fires.  It is ONLY when all characters are removed that the event no longer fires.   I'm trying to be as clear as I can.  I apologize for any confusion thus far.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite baffling, I can't seem to reproduce your problem. Here is the code I've used to get it to work, perhaps you can compare the code to what I've done and see if there is any difference.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var txt = new TextBox
                          {
                              Text = "Initial Text"
                          };

            txt.TextChanged += ThisTextBoxChanged;
            form1.Controls.Add(txt);
        }

        private static void ThisTextBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I had to be away for a bit and just getting back to things.  I'll try this out and see how it goes.